# Does one have to check some additional hypothesis to apply the implicit function theorem for infinite dimensional spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, functional-equations

Let $L : B_1 \rightarrow B_1$ be an isomorphism of Banach spaces 
(i.e., L is a bijective bounded linear operator) and 
$A: B_1 \rightarrow B_2$ a non linear operator. Consider the following equation 
$$ Lu_t + Au_t = \xi_t$$
where $u_t$ is unknown and $\xi_t$ is known. 
Suppose we know that $u_0$ is a solution to the above equation, i.e. 
$$ Lu_0 + Au_0 = \xi_0.$$ 
Furthermore, suppose that the linearization of the operator $A$ at 
the point $u_0$ is the zero operator (said in a different way, the 
linearization of $L+A$ at $u_0$ is the operator $L$). Is it correct to 
say that if $\xi_t$ is sufficiently close to $\xi_0$, then there 
exists a unique solution $u_t$, sufficiently close to $u_0$ to the 
equation
$$ Lu_t + Au_t = \xi_t$$
?

If $B_1$ and $B_2$ were finite dimensional spaces, I think this is correct. 
Does one have to check some additional hypothesis in infinte dimensions?

Comment: It seems to me that the only thing that is missing is to check that $A\in C^1$.

Comment: And you do need to check this, even in finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Guiseppe. Thank you for making this observation. One further question: I suppose it is possible in principle that $A$ could be $C^1$ with respect to one norm, but not $C^1$ with respect to a different norm? Typically in infinite dimensional spaces one can put inequivalent norms.

Comment: @Ritwik: I am no expert, but I am sure that this phenomenon may happen. You can probably construct abstract examples with the techniques of functional analysis: for instance, I am ready to bet that there exist a Banach space $X$ and a linear operator $L$ defined on it such that $L$ is bounded with respect to a norm and not bounded with respect to another. In this case you have that $L\in C^\infty$ with respect to a norm but $L$ is not even continuous with respect to the other.[...]

Comment: [...]I also think that *concrete* examples exist. I see that people in calculus of variations and PDE often choose norms with great care in order to ensure that their functionals are $C^1$.